# Multiple DateTrigger inside Style.Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building sync text visualizer using `FontAwesome` unicode text, and in order to change from play to pause, and from any condition to sync, I use two `DataTrigger`s that are bind to two different `bool` properties.

###### I must say that it work flawlessly except of an error I get sometimes when I "touch" the binding area.

The error from VS 2022:

> TriggerAction object must be associated with one and only one trigger object

After I run the program, the error disappear, and i don't get any run-time error.

Is it really an error to have two different `DataTrigger`s inside one `<Style.Triggers>` or just a bug in VS 2022?

#### My code

```cs
 <TextBlock 
      FontSize="26"
      Padding="15 0" 
      TextAlignment="Center" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
      <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
              <Setter Property="Text" Value="&#xf144;"/>
              <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="font awesome 6 free regular"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2FAA55"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <!--Pause symbol-->
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SyncStatus, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B03050"/>
                      <Setter Property="Text" Value="&#xf28b;"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <!--Sync symbol-->
                  <!--Error is in this binding-->
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSyncing, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3050B0"/>
                      <Setter Property="Text" Value="&#xf2f1;"/>
                      <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                          <Setter.Value>
                              <RotateTransform Angle="360"/>
                          </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="font awesome 6 free solid"/>
                      <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                          <BeginStoryboard>
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation
                                      To="0"
                                      From="360"
                                      Duration="0:0:1"
                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </BeginStoryboard>
                      </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </TextBlock.Style>
  </TextBlock>
```

Comment: *"I must say that it work flawlessly except of an error I get sometimes when i "touch" the binding erea."*: what does this mean, is the code you have posted working or not? If you have trouble with your bindings then you must post the data context too. There is nothing one can do right now. *"Is it really an error to have two different DataTriggers inside one `<Style.Triggers>"*: no it's not an error. Style.Triggers is a TriggerCollection.

Comment: By "touch" the binding erea, i mean for example adding comma, adding `Mode` keyword, or any change to the `Binding` string.
So it is possible to have two `DataTrigger` in one object/Style?